# Run front end of website on one domain and backend of website on another domain

Tags: php, mysql

how can we run front end of website on one domain and back end of website on another domain. i am using **php** and **MySQL** for this

Comment: Your point isn't clear. Are you asking about hosting. Plz post your code if someone is able to find out what you want.

Comment: From what you are asking, You could do this. you would just have to make it so that the Other domain with the backend on has a landing page so if a users hits it they can redirect back to the main website. and you would have to choose one of your hosts that your website is on as the main data center to run the back end. And all links to of the main website would have to external.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can only answer unspecific.

You have to configure your webserver(usually apache) for two domains. Then you either work on the same database as the live-server or have some publishing mechanism for the backend data to go live.